# Querying XML elements with identical name with Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductTypes>
    <ProductType Name="MyProduct">
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <Pattern Length="1" AllowedCharacters="ABCD"/>
        <Pattern Length="7" AllowedCharacters="EFGH"/>
    </ProductType>
</ProductTypes>
```

Using Linq to XML I can successfully extract information from any number of the element `ProductType`. However I also need the information from all of the elements `Pattern`.

```
        XElement xml = XElement.Load("pattern_config.xml");

        var productTypes = from productType in xml.Elements("ProductType")
                           select new {
                               Name = productType.Attribute("Name").Value,
                               Amount = Convert.ToInt32(productType.Element("Amount").Value)
                               // How to get all Pattern elements from that ProductType?
                           };
```

How can I do this? Or would you recommend another way accessing this XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest queries.

```
 var productTypes = from productType in xml.Elements("ProductType")
                select new {
                   Name = productType.Attribute("Name").Value,
                   Amount = Convert.ToInt32(productType.Element("Amount").Value),
                   // How to get all Pattern elements from that ProductType?
                   Patterns = from patt in productType.Elements("Pattern")
                              select new { Length = int.Parse(patt.Attribute("Length").Value),
                                           .... }
                 };
```